# Как исправить ошибку 'int' object is not subscriptable? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно сделать бинарный поиск по списку. В первую строку вписывается сам список а второй строкой какой элемент нужно найти. Но на 11 строке появилась ошибка `'int' object is not subscriptable`.
Вот сам код:

```
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
a.sort()
print(a)

b = int(input())

mid  = len(a) // 2
high = len(a) -  1
low  = 0

while b[mid] != a and low <= high:
    
    if a > b[mid]:
        low  = mid + 1
        
    else:
        high = mid - 1
        
    mid = (low + high) // 2


if low > high:
    print('No value')
else:
    print('ID =', mid)
```

Comment: В b у вас целое число записано (`b = int(input())`), скорее всего должно быть `a[mid] != b` вместо `b[mid] != a` (сравнение элемента списка a с числом b), и аналогично ниже `a[mid]` вместо `b[mid]`.

Comment: спасибо, я действительно допустил там ошибку, но всё ещё осталось TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: Значит только в одном месте исправили, нужно везде изменить `b[mid]` на `a[mid]`. Либо исправили, но что-то другое сломали.